# Why it is a group action?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let a group $G$ acts on a vector space $V$ and let  $f$ be a function on $V$. The action of an element $g \in G$  defined by the rule $g f(x)=f(g^{-1} x), \forall x \in V.$

A typical  proof from a book has the form 
$$
g_1 g_2 f(x)=g_1 f(g_2^{-1} x)=f(g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1} x)=f((g_1 g_2)^{-1} x)
$$

**Question.**  Why here $g_1 f(g_2^{-1} x)=f(g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1} x)$?  Seems have  to be $g_1 f(g_2^{-1} x)=f(g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1} x)$.

Comment: No, it is correct as written, just follow the definition.

Comment: When I followed  the definition I have got $g_1 f(g_2^{-1} x)=f(g_1^{-1}g_2^{-1} x)$.Where is my mistake?

Comment: @Leox: you have to insert $g_1$ right next to $x$. Another way to say this is to write $h(x) = f(g_2^{-1} x)$ and write $g_1 h(x) = h(g_1^{-1} x) = f(g_2^{-1} g_1^{-1} x)$.

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me clarify the confusion. Elements $g \in G$ act on the functions on $V$. Thus, if we have

$$g_{1} \cdot f(g_{2}^{-1} x)$$

we need to identify what the the function is. Is the function here $f$? No, because the function is meant to take as input elements of $V$, but inside of $f$ we have a group element $g_{2}^{-1}$. The actual function here is

$$h = f \circ g_{2}^{-1}$$

since this takes as input $x \in V$. Thus

$$g_{1} \cdot h(x) = h(g_{1}^{-1}x) = f \circ g_{2}^{-1} \circ g_{1}^{-1} (x)$$